# PEG.js matching word from Array

Tags: javascript, peg

I have problem with PEG.js and matching words.

It looks like this:
`Words = "stack"/"overflow"/"stackoverflow"` - when I try to match "stackoverflow" it shows error `Expected end of input but "o" found.` so it found `stack` and thought it was end - `overflow` was left.

You can try it here: https://pegjs.org/online
and paste:

`Text = Word
Word = "stack"/"overflow"/"stackoverflow"` and try with word "stackoverflow"

I don't wont to change words in array.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PegJS tries to match the first value. Only if this does not succeed, it will try the second one and so on.
As in your case `stack` can be matched, it will not continue trying to match anything else.

This problem will oftentimes appear, when one match is a prefix of another one. In such cases, you should start the list with the "longer" terms and put the prefixes towards the end:

```
Text = Word
Word = "stackoverflow"/"stack"/"overflow"
```

You could also match for multiple words. In this case both `stack` and `overflow` will get matched, but not `stackoverflow`.

```
Text = Word*
Word = "stack"/"overflow"/"stackoverflow"
```

Comment: So there is no other way then to reorganize it?

Comment: @Filemon279 See my edit. What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for edit but it won't work for me. "stackoverflow" was bad example since in my array I do not have "overflow" so it wont find rest of word in array. I thought it is other way then to sort my array but I will go with it. Thank you for your help.